# Можно ли повернуть обьект в unity2D по определенной траектории? [закрыто]

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Описание: Есть обьект, который нужно повернуть с положения А в положение В.
Поворачиваю через Quaternion.Lerp (A , B , speed).

Проблема: Поворот должен осуществляться по "неоптимальной" траектории, то бишь по красной (См рисунок)

Вопрос: Можно ли "заставить" обьект поворачиваться по определенной траектории?
(Вопрос глобальный, не только по этому примеру)

P.S. Я новичок, не бейте палками :)

Comment: Google -> "
unity spline path movement"

Comment: Спасибо большое :)